# How to set a string from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a text file which always has one line, how could I set a string for the first line of the text file in C#?

e.g. line1 in test.txt = string version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines("c:\\test.txt", new[]{"myString"});
```

To read a textfile with only one line into a variable

```
var str = File.ReadAllText("c:\\test.txt");
```

Comment: Forgive me but, shouldnt it be ReadAllLines?

Comment: From your question "how  could I set a string for the first line of the text file" I assumed you wanted to "set" the string to the text file.

Comment: Sorry, no, I wanted it the other way around

Answer (score 2):

A text file is not line based, so you can't change a specific line in a text file, you would need to rewrite the entire file.

If your file only ever contains that single line, you can just rewrite the file with the new string:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, newValue);
```

#### Edit:

As you said that what you actually want to do is to read the file, it's different... If there is only a single line in the file, you can read the entire file:

```
string line = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

If the file could contain more than a single line, you would have to open the file and only read the first line:

```
string line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
  line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

You could also use `File.ReadAllLines` and get the first line from the result, but that would be wasteful if the file contains a lot of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).